# Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : cannot open the connection - how to fix it?

Tags: r, printing

I already searched multiple times but can't understand why the msg pops up. Please help me out. My code is as follows:

```
(WD <- getwd())
if (!is.null(WD)) setwd(WD)

indata      = paste0(WD,"/US_ind.rda","", collapse = NULL)

library(haven)
library(AER)
library(sandwich)
library(lmtest)
library(pracma)
....

regTableA<- stargazer(plm_base_gamma,plm_base_delta, plm_base_both, 
                      font.size = "footnotesize",
                      out = "output/regTableA.tex",
                      column.sep.width = "2pt",
                      se = stderror,
                      title = "Zillow data")
```

At the last step, I want to export the table into tex form. But the error msg repeatedly pops up. How can I fix this?

Comment: Typically this error means that the path to the output file or directory is incorrect _i.e._ does not exist.

Comment: @neilfws The problem solved! I designated the accurate directory. Thanks for your tips.